# A better way to remove hash from URL instead of using pushState

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small script to remove the hash from a url, however it is causing a problem. Because I am effecting the history, it does not allow the user to use the back button in the browser to go back to the previous page they were on. Is there possibly a cleaner way to do this?

```
//Tab links in navbar:
$(document).ready(function() {
    function navHash() {
        var hash = document.location.hash;
        if (hash) {
            history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
            $('.nav-stacked a[href="'+hash+'"]').tab('show');
        }
    }
    navHash();
    $(window).on('hashchange', navHash)
});
```

Comment: Use `replaceState` instead of `pushState` if you don't want to keep history

Comment: @abhishekkannojia thank you that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone else stumbles across this question, here is the corrected code.

```
//Tab links in navbar:
$(document).ready(function() {
    function navHash() {
        var hash = document.location.hash;
        if (hash) {
            history.replaceState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
            $('.nav-stacked a[href="'+hash+'"]').tab('show');
        }
    }
    navHash();
    $(window).on('hashchange', navHash)
});
```